# How to add custom attachments files in order emails

Tags: magento-1.9, send-mail

I have a custom cron job in my magento store from where I send order email to customer second time but this time I want to attach some custom files to this order email.

I am using `sendNewOrderEmail()` function.

How to attach custom files in my cron job file?

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/email-attachments-by-fooman.html

Comment: My custom files will be dynamic for each order in cron job file.